Filebeat log rotation configuration assistance needed
I use Filebeat to monitor a log file. When the file reaches 10 MB, it starts writing from the beginning again while retaining the following lines. Can you help me configure this file?
For example, if my log file contains:
1
2
3
4

When it reaches 10 MB, it restarts writing from the beginning like this:
11
2
3
4

Thank you.
